# Como reconstruir uma Listview.builder usando outra consulta ao apertar um botão

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Olá, tenho uma Listview.builder que está construindo meu [Feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3d04.png).

Aqui a minha Referência:

```
CollectionReference post = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');
```

Parte da **Listview:**

```
Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: post.snapshots(),
        builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                      streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
```

Quero mudar/filtrar essa consulta ao apertar os [botões](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCOBF.png), tentei adicionar um where na referência da minha coleção porém não deu certo, e preciso que cada botão seja uma consulta/filtro diferente, então não sei o que fazer. Alguém pode me dar uma luz? desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -3):

Vc pode dar uma olhada nesta doc do firebase falando sobre query [Queries Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart)

Como vc esta usando um stream builder, vc só vai precisar recarregar sua lista com os dados filtrados. Caso os dados sejam diferente vc pode usar até mesmo um setState para alterar entre seu a lista atual e a nova que vc quer filtrar.